# Linq странный возврат

Tags: c#, linq

Всем привет. Не могу понять почему в этом коде переменная `v` имеет тип `IEnumerable<string[]>`. Ведь по коду я вначале фильтрую слова начинающеися на `А`, потом идет перебор через переменную `x` и конечно, должен возвращаться некоторый `IEnumerable<string>` но как я понял, то возвращается массив массивов и следовательно данная форма `foreach` не работает. Почему ?

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] s = new string[] { "Avel", "Pavel", "Mavel", "Musia", "Pussia", "Mama", "Artik", "Purn", "Acvelon" };
    var v = from st in s
            where !st.StartsWith("A")
            select s
                into x
                where x.Length > 4
                select x;

    foreach(string str in v)
    {

    }
}
```

ПС Знаю, что запрос можно сделать проще, но мне просто нужно для себя понять, почему такой возврат

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо потому что переменная s тоже string[].
Достаточно будет select s поменять на select st

Comment: Точно !! Не зря мне DreamChild говорил, чтобы я нормально переменные называл, в итоге сам запутался в своих именах